# Pandas: Merging two dataframe with diffrent time index

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, sklearn-pandas

I have a large dateset that includes categorical data which are my labels ( non-uniform timestamp). I have another dataset which is aggregate of the measurement. 
When I want to assemble these two dataset, they have two different timestamp ( aggregated vs non-aggregated).

Categorical dataframe (df_Label)

```
count   1185
unique  10
top         ABCD
freq    1165
```

Aggregated Dataset (MeasureAgg), 
In order to assemble the label dataframe with measurement dataframe.
I use `df_Label=df_Label.reindex(MeasureAgg.index, method='nearest')`
The issue is that the result of this reindexing will eliminate many of my labels, so the df.describe() will be:

```
count   4
unique  2
top     ABCD
freq    3
```

I looked in two several lines of where the labels get replaced by nan but couldn't find any indication of where this come from.

I was suspicious  that this issue might be due clustering of the labels in between two timestamp which eliminate many of them but this is not the case.

I tried this for fabricated dataset and it work as expected but not sure why is not working in my case `df_Label=df_Label.reindex(MeasureAgg.index, method='nearest')`

my apology on vague nature of my question, I couldn't replicate the issue with  fabricated dataset( for fabricated dataset it worked fine). I would greatly appreciate if any one can guide me with alternative way/modified way that I can assemble these two dataframes.

Thanks in advance

Update:
There is only timestamp since it is mostly missing data

`df_Label.head(5)`

```
Time
2000-01-01 00:00:10.870    NaN
2000-01-01 00:00:10.940    NaN
2000-01-01 00:00:11.160    NaN
2000-01-01 00:00:11.640    NaN
2000-01-01 00:00:12.460    NaN
Name: SUM, dtype: object
```

`df_Label.describe()`

```
count             1185
unique              10
top       9_33_2_0_0_0
freq              1165
Name: SUM, dtype: object
```

`MeasureAgg.head(5)`

```
Time    mean    std skew    kurt
2000-01-01 00:00:00 0.0 0.0     
2010-01-01 00:00:00 0.0         
2015-01-01 00:00:00             
2015-12-01 00:00:00             
2015-12-01 12:40:00 0.0
```

`MeasureAgg.describe()`

```
    mean    std skew    kurt
count   407.0   383.0   382.0   382.0
mean    487.3552791234544 35.67631749396375 -0.7545081710390299 2.52171909979003
std 158.53524231679074 43.66050329988979    1.3831195437535115  6.72280956322486
min     0.0      0.0      -7.526780108501018  -1.3377292623812096
25% 474.33696969696973 11.5126181533734 -1.1790982769904146 -0.4005545816076801
50% 489.03428571428566 13.49696931937243 -0.2372819584684056 -0.017202890096714274
75% 532.3371929824561 51.40084557371704 0.12755009341999793 1.421205718986767
max 699.295652173913 307.8822231525122 1.2280152015331378   66.9243304128838
```

Comment: If you can't find a way to fabricate a dataset that reproduces the problem - I'm not sure anyone can help easily...

Comment: @JonClements I am not looking for exact answer, but more looking for any alternative way to reindex the dataset to merge with anotherone. or if anyone know that `reindex(MeasureAgg.index, method='nearest')` can behave in this unexpected manner.

Comment: Can you paste in `df.head(5)` for both dataframes as well as `df.describe()` ?

Comment: @cardamom I updated the question and added the information's for dataframe. Thanks